# docker symfony with nginx GET routes not found

Tags: php, docker, symfony, nginx

I have deployed a symfony app using docker. it has two containers: one for my symfony app and another one for nginx

I load the homepage ok but it is making an ajax GET call to fetch `/articles`. I get error in docker logs:

`nginx  | 2022/08/24 19:29:10 [error] 30#30: *1 open() "/var/www/app/public/articles" failed (2: No such file or directory)`

in my browser console

```
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.23.1</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure why the GET route is translating to a directory in the `public` folder ? `/articles` is just a get route to get data from database

here is my nginx config

```
server {

    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
    root /var/www/app/public/;
    index index.php;
    server_name mydomain.com;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        root /var/www/app/public/;
        fastcgi_pass   app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include   /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you just access `/`, the server naturally looks for the `index` you named (index.php, in the line `index index.php`).

nginx will - besides from that - always try to find the exact file that matches the URI - if no matching rewrite/location/whatever is found - for example `/articles`. This is obviously the default for a web server like nginx, serving files whose path on disk match the URI. However, you don't have a file called `articles` in your public folder (which might have had existed, from nginx's standpoint).

But it doesn't find that, so it will try to match configured `location`s. But `/articles` doesn't match `\.php$` (obviously, but it did match `index.php` before).

Your nginx config is missing the `try_files` directive which is usually used in routing without a matching file structure. It is also missing the `location /` block, which it would fallback on, if no other location was matching. Your config therefor doesn't apparently represent what you are intending to achieve...

You should take a look on how to [configure nginx for symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/web_server_configuration.html#nginx) - note the `try_files` in the `location /` block, which does the magic there, rewriting all urls to a parameter on the index.php script (entry point for symfony) and thus allowing symfony to work its routing magic.